# merging 2 lists as a key value pair in python

Tags: python

Input:

```
l1="model,color,brand,value"
l2="2009,red,car,100000"
```

output:

```
l3="model:2009,color:red,brand:car,value=100000"
```

is the above thing possible?

Comment: `l1` and `l2` are strings but look like lists and `l3` is a string but looks like a dict. I'm curious as to why you need strings here.

Comment: Your desired `l3` seems weird; is the `=` a typo?

Comment: If it isn't every answer on the page(at this point in time) is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `l3` a dictionary, which stores key-value pairs:

```
>>> l3 = dict( zip(l1.split(','), l2.split(',')) )
>>> l3
{'brand': 'car', 'color': 'red', 'model': '2009', 'value': '100000'}
```

But if you just need a string, you can use `join`:

```
>>> l3 = ','.join([ '%s:%s' % (k, v) for k, v in zip(l1.split(','), l2.split(',')) ])
>>> l3
'model:2009,color:red,brand:car,value:100000'
```

Note that `l1` and `l2` are not `list`s, but strings. Thus we can convert them to lists by splitting on the commas, e.g. `l1.split(',')`.

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't lists, rather strings. You need to convert them to lists and zip:

```
>>> l1.split(',') # split string by comma
['model', 'color', 'brand', 'value']
>>> l3 = zip(l1.split(','), l2.split(','))
>>> l3 # zipped list
[('model', '2009'), ('color', 'red'), ('brand', 'car'), ('value', '100000')]
>>> ','.join('%s:%s' % l for l in l3)     # convert back to string
'model:2009,color:red,brand:car,value:100000'
```

Also, you might find `collections.namedtuple` useful:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> NT = namedtuple('data', tuple(l1.split(',')))
>>> row = NT(*l2.split(','))
>>> row
data(model='2009', color='red', brand='car', value='100000')
>>> row.model
'2009'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> l1 = "model,color,brand,value"
>>> l2 = "2009,red,car,100000"
>>> l3 = ",".join(a+":"+b for a,b in zip(l1.split(","),l2.split(",")))
>>> l3
'model:2009,color:red,brand:car,value:100000'
```

Comment: that's not the output in the question

Comment: @Noelkd: Yes, DSM noticed that a while ago. We're still waiting for the OP's reply.

Answer (score 2):

```
l3 = ",".join(":".join(pair) for pair in zip(l1.split(","), l2.split(","))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a list of key value pairs and the accepted answer isn't the answer you showed in your post/question, here's an alternative interpretation (a list of dictionaries).

Code:

```
keys = 'model,color,brand,value'
values = '2009,red,car,10000'
zcar = [ {key: val} for (key, val) in zip(keys.split(','),values.split(','))]
```

Answer:

```
[{'model': '2009'}, {'colour': 'red'}, {'brand': 'car'}, {'value': '10000'}]
```

Any positive criticism gratefully received.