# Generate Key value pairs from two lists in python

Tags: python, list, key-value

I have 2 lists:

```py
list1 = ["Mar 04", "Mar 05", "Mar 06", "Mar 07", "Mar 08", "Mar 09"]
lsit2 = [72888494.4, 151676281, 142677, 5865.698, 107451, 945203.08]
```

I want to generate key value pairs which look like this:

```py
lst = [
    {"x": "Mar 04", "y": "72888494.4"},
    {"x": "Mar 05", "y": "151676281"},
    {"x": "Mar 06", "y": "142677"},
]
```

How should I do it?

Comment: `[{'x': a, 'y': b} for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: In case you really need the "y" values to be strings, you should convert them accordingly: `[{'x': a, 'y': str(b)} for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merging 2 lists as a key value pair in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795307/merging-2-lists-as-a-key-value-pair-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```py
lst = [{'x': list1_element, 'y': list2_element} for list1_element, list2_element in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Or you can do it without any functions:

```py
lst = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    lst.append({'x': list1[i], 'y': list2[i]})
```